# Outputting Max min and average from a randomized array?

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I was wondering if anyone can help me with something I was struggling all day with.

In the code below I dictated an array of randomized numbers from which I have to have pull out the max the min and the average. It all looks fine and good (such a compact software!) But I attain a weird output. I believe I have a finger on what the problem is (say I'm finding the max for the first number but the next number is smaller the software will think that's the biggest number even though integer 14 may be bigger) but I have no idea how to go about fixing this. The minimum value I have no idea why it's wrong it keeps saying it's zero and the average value stays anywhere from 10-19 which is impossible considering the range of randomized numbers goes from 1 to 1000. I was never taught how to organize random numbers in an array, so I just have no idea how to go about fixing this. Any help will be super awesome! I really struggled with this program and even scrapped it multiple times, if it's only a simple mistake I overlooked I would feel awfully embarrassed I'll post the code and an example output below.

Thanks for taking your time, I hope you have a wonderful day!

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;
int main()
{

//Defining variables
//DEFINE SIZE
const int ARRAY_SIZE =20;
//Index variable
int i;
//For finding average
double sum=0;


double max_value;

double min_value;
//Keep all numbers sane
cout.precision(5);

srand((unsigned)time(0));

double main_array[ARRAY_SIZE];

//Header
cout << "Element number \t\t" << "Random Number\n\n" << endl;


//Assigning random values into array.
for (i=0; i< ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{

max_value=0;
min_value=0;

//Randomizer
double ran = 0 + (rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/(1000-0)));

main_array[i] = ran;
cout << "\t" << i << "\t\t" << main_array[i] << endl;

//Find average
sum= (sum + main_array[i]);
sum= sum/(ARRAY_SIZE+1);



//Initalizing
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{

if ( min_value > ran) 
min_value = main_array[i];
if (max_value < ran)
max_value = main_array[i];
}



}
cout <<"Average Value is: "       << sum << endl;
cout <<"\nThe Minimum Value Is: " << min_value << endl;
cout <<"\nThe Maximum value Is: " << max_value << endl;




system ("pause");
return 0;

}
```

An output example would be

Element number          Random Number

```
    0               791.62
    1               542.04
    2               879.57
    3               875.39
    4               38.057
    5               73.702
    6               973.27
    7               22.431
    8               830.26
    9               444.59
    10              276.89
    11              888.12
    12              827.17
    13              900.45
    14              883.72
    15              201.15
    16              317.64
    17              649.83
    18              443.98
    19              683


Average Value is: 33.603

The Minimum Value Is: 0

The Maximum value Is: 791.62
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: can you use the `algorithm` library?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you *must* do otherwise, use `std::min_element` to find the minimum, `std::max_element` to find the maximum, and `std::accumulate` to find the sum.

If you absolutely *must* do this on your own, you usually want to initialize your minimum and maximum to the first element in the collection, then look for others that are smaller/larger:

```
int mininum = array[0];
int maximum = array[0];

for (int i=1; i<array_size; i++) {
    if (array[i] < minimum)
        minimum = array[i];
    if (array[i] > maximum)
        maximum = array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you start looping, create a min, max, and total. Then when you are creating each element of the array, also check whether it is less than the min or more than the max. Also add that number to your total. At the end, outside the loop, divide the total by the number of elements to get your average.

You definitely shouldn't be iterating through the whole array each time you add an element, and you shouldn't be resetting your min and max each time through the loop. You also shouldn't set your min to 0 if all your numbers are going to be more than 0, because it will never be updated.